# Redux mapDispatchToProps as object argument not working also not showing anything expect state in dev tool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, thunk

Hi everyone i saw other similar type questions but i still cant resolve my answer. I am trying to authenticate the user by calling api and use thunk as middleware to pass function in my **MapDispatchToProp** but i cannot figure out whats the problem . I can ensure that api part is working properly. 
Only **first two files** are important for this question rest all i pasted for any extra info you reqire.
Also i can succesfuly get **token** from my api so that means form data is also submitting properly.

Please **also take look at last file** whether i connected thunk properly or not i am having doubt of this though i copied code from their docs

**PROBLEM** : **authUser** is not returning dispatch action

**Assumption**: every time user gives correct email and password and **SET_CURRENT_USER** shold be invoked as action

**Process**: authUser function is called in Main component which is a container component and it should dispatch the SET_CURRENT_USER as action but authUser isn't changing anything.

**action/auth.js  file(file which handles authentication and should dispatch action)**

```
// this will handle auth action
import apiCall from '../../services/api'
import {SET_CURRENT_USER} from '../actionTypes'


function authUser(data){

       let response= new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
                    try{
                            let responseData=await apiCall("post","/api/auth/logIn",data)

                            resolve(responseData)
                         }catch(err){
                            reject(err)
                    }
        })
       let responseAnswer= response.then((data)=>{
            return ({type:SET_CURRENT_USER,user:data})
        }).catch((err)=>{
            /// ignore error part for now
            console.log(err.message)
        })

        // return of response part is dispatched
        return dispatch(responseAnswer) ;




}

export default authUser;
```

**Main.js file which invokes user auth function (it uses a component to get data)**

```
// this file is responsible for handling routes logic 
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Switch , Redirect ,withRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Auth from '../components/Auth'
import authUser from '../stores/action/auth'
function Main(props){
    console.log(props.state)
    return(
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
                 <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/signUp">
                 <Auth heading={"Welcome to warbler"} signUp buttonText="Sign Up" />
            </Route> 
            <Route exact path="/login">
                 <Auth authUser={authUser} heading={"Welcome Back :)"} buttonText="Log In" />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return (
        {
           state:state
        }
    )
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{authUser})(Main))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the mistakes i did. These things were just the combinations of the previous stackOverflow questions that i did combined.I wasted my one whole day in it. So i thought i will tell so that others don't do these ones again. Also none of these are new errors they are just the combined ones.

1st Mistake --> i did was that i assumed **action creators with thunk as middleware** are just like any other functions that will return a dispatch but i was **wrong**.

```
  // return of response part is dispatched
    return dispatch(responseAnswer) ;
```

> What i learnt is that action creators with thunk return **functions** with dispatch as there arguments.

correct way would be -->

```
 // i have to return a function 

//not directly return dispatch(with something) 
function authUser(data){
   // now it will be correct since its returning a func 
//with dispactch as argument
    return (dispatch)=>{
        let response=new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            try{
                let fetchedData=await (apiCall("post","/api/auth/logIn",data))
                console.log(fetchedData.data)
                resolve(fetchedData.data)
            }catch(err){
                reject(err)
            }
        })


        response.then((data,x)=>{

            dispatch({type:SET_CURRENT_USER,user:data})

        }).catch((err)=>err)


    }

}
```

These returned functions use the dispatch argument to dispatch the actions.I was confused that we return dispatch with arguments as (action to be called) **but in actual**--->

we pass the dispatch as argument in a function and return that function. Inside this function we call dispatch whenever our async requests get completed to change the state.

2nd Mistake ---> I assumed the callbacks of .then can be used to return data like ..

```
var x = promisefunc.then((data)=>(data))
```

i thought this would return the data but this had been told many times in stackOverflow also that these type of statements assign x value as a promise and doesnot return the data.

3rd Mistake---> I was confused how dispatch is passed as argument whenever we declare statements like below and passed actionCreators.

```
connect(mapStateToProps,{authUser})(Main)
```

but then i read in redux docs and found this --->

```
**// Thunk middleware knows how to handle functions.
  // It passes the dispatch method as an argument to the function,
  // thus making it able to dispatch actions itself.**
```

Then i figured in actual we only pass redux the plain objects what thunk does is whenever we pass a reduxActionCreator as function it is handled by thunk and then thunk helps to dispatch the action from inside of that function .

I may be wrong in the concepts of what i understood please correct me If you think i mistaken somewhere.